# Viewing a specific category on Magento frontend crashes the site

Tags: category

I can navigate through my website no problem, add an item to cart, proceed to checkout etc.

The moment I click on the "Accessories" category we have set up, the website freezes, and then I can no longer access the site on that browser for a good hour or so.

If I change browser, I can view the website fine, but then if I click on 'Accessories' again, it freezes up.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: There's probably some JS code executing on that category. Can you open the browser's console and read the logs?

Comment: Hi. I just went into a 3rd browser to give this a try. In the console window it just came up with GET: http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/accessories and that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLVED***

I had an issue with reindexing being stuck. My hosting provider said "Php memory limit set on the server was causing the problem. I have increased the memory limit set on the server to 1GB and now your reindexing is working fine"

This in turn also fixed my issue of the magento category crashing the website.